# Set the value of a pointer in a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a struct like so:

```
typedef struct foo {
   int *bar;
   foo();
} foo;
```

and say an int like so : `int i = 2;`.

if I wish to make `int* p1 = new int;` point to `i` I simply go: `p1 = &i;`

How do I make `foo.bar` point to `i`?

I think the constructor needs to do the following:

```
foo::foo() {
   bar = new int;
}
```

But I don't know how to make `foo.bar` point to `i`.

Comment: This is definitely not C. function as a member inside a struct is not valid in C.

Comment: Is this C or C++ question? Because your struct is written in C, while the `new` keyword is C++.

Comment: You seem to wish to have a memory leak. Here `p1 = &i;` you leak the thing `p1` pointer to before.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion of ideas here. (e.g.: in C++ you don't need to `typedef` structs, calling `bar = new int;` looks like it will cause a memory leak as you reassign it later and I don't understand where your problem is in assigning a value (or where you have an instance of the struct))

Comment: Sorry its c++. Basically I am asking what is the equivalent of `p1 = &i`the pointer were member of a struct? `foo.bar = &i`? How would I access the int now pointed to by bar? `foo.*bar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

Multiple people were correct about the memory leak.

```
typedef struct foo {
        int *bar;
} foo;
```

To deference a pointer member of a struct:

```
int main() {
   foo fooIn;
   int i = 2;

   fooIn.bar = &i; // have the int pointer 'bar' point to the value i;

   int *barVal = (int*)fooIn.bar;
   printf("bar points to: %d, *barVal) // prints "bar points to: 2"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in a real example you should make the construtor "foo()" initialize bar and a dtor which deletes it;
this is just an example how to use pointer to a struct to access members:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct foo
{
    int* bar;
    foo(){}

}FOO, *PFOO;


int main(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{

    struct foo* ptrFoo = new foo;
//  PFOO pFoo = new foo; // you can use this also 
    ptrFoo->bar = new int(10);

    cout << ptrFoo->bar << endl;
    cout << (*ptrFoo).bar << endl;
    cout << *ptrFoo->bar << endl;
    cout << *(*ptrFoo).bar << endl;

    delete ptrFoo->bar;
    ptrFoo->bar = NULL;

    delete ptrFoo;
    ptrFoo = NULL;


    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```